# Making XY To Line not give shortest distance in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, xy, flow-map, antimeridian, new-zealand

I am creating a very simple map through XY to Line in AcrGIS. However, since the destination is New Zealand and located at the bottom corner of global maps it creates the following.

Is there a way to make the lines on the left side of the map get connected to New Zealand similar to others seen on the map?

I have tried moving the New Zealand polygon to the center as its just for show but no luck. I hav tried diffeerent Line Types in the tool as well.

[image: XY to Line for New Zealand]

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your quetsion: if you intend to connect America to NZ having your lines crossing the Atlantic Ocean, that is not the shortest path to NZ. otherwise, have a look at my answer that can give you an idea of what's going on on your map.

Comment: @umbe1987 thanks, sorry I wasn’t probably explicit that the results are correct. What I want is just for aesthetic purpose. It seems there is no way really, I tried changing the projection, even moving the NZ polygon to the centre but still the way that tool works will give the same results.

Comment: @Hank I'm curious why "moving the NZ polygon to the centre" would give the same results. Maybe you could *edit* your question with some more information about *how* you did that and *what* the result was.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you see is the right result. The fact that those lines seem "long" to you it's because they are rendered on a flat representation of the Earth (a projection). Hence, if you try to draw by hands (editing) a line connecting a point to New Zealand directly and then you measure it, you should see it is longer than the others.

This is due to the fact that in reality the shape of the Earth is comparable to a sphere, and so those "long" lines represent the shortest geodesic path connecting two points as seen on a specific bidimensional representation (a projection) of a three dimensional sphere.

You can see the difference between a planar and a geodesic length on a Web Mercator projection at this link: http://ekenes.github.io/esri-js-samples/ge-length/

Comment: I don't think OP is concerned about geodesic lines and projections, but more that there appears to be two "origins", and only one of them is coincident with mainland New Zealand, the other is on the other side of the antimeridian. I guess Hank's goal is aesthetic.

Comment: Agreed, I'm not sure this is possible without doing it manually since there is technically an infinite number of "non-shortest distance" potential routes wrapping around a sphere.  Adobe Illustrator may be the way to go on this.

Comment: I agree too, let's just wait for the OP feedback and I'll probably delete the answer if he/she confirms.

Comment: @alphabetasoup yes, exactly , I not not concered about projection it just for aesthetic purpose.

Comment: @mikeLdub True, I tried to do it kinda manually in ArcGIS but seems Adobe Suit might be the way I could manipulate it. In the case no need for this tool really.